# Why do i have this gap and how do i remove it

Tags: css, html

I have come across a slight problem, I set my nav bar to 100% width, and now i have a gap on the right hand side of my page and a horizontal scroll bar for the page, I do not know why it has done this. Please see code attached.
he code is:

```
nav {

    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #42C2DA;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
nav ul {

    padding: 7px;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 100%;

}
nav li {

    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;

}
nav li a {

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;

}

nav li a:link a:visited {

    font-weight: bold;

}
```

Could someone explain where i am going wrong... or what is happening here.
I dont have 10 rep so cant post a pic.

Comment: Maybe you can post a link to a example page or JSFiddle?

Comment: You'll need to post your HTML as well.

Comment: don't forget that margins aren't counted in `width` by default. e.g. `width: 100px; margin: 5px` results in a 110px-wide box.

Comment: "so cant post a pic." - You don't want to post one anyway - if you post a jsfiddle (as others have stated) it's a LOT easier for people to toy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nav bar has `padding:6px`; this adds 6px to all sides of the div, meaning the actual width of that element isn't `100%`, but rather `100% + 12px`.

To fix this, try using `box-sizing: border-box`, which makes it so that your padding is calculated into your specified 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal scroll bar is probably because You've set:

- `width: 100%`
- `padding: 6px`

And for that reason You will have total width: 100% of viewport + 12px

Set `box-sizing: border-box` and  this fix Your problem - [more info about box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).